# Is it safe to create a self-made paylink in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-5, payment

For a payment system that I am building in Laravel 5.4 I need to create a page where a customer can go to and pay a bill. Right now I am creating a page for every payment with a key slug generated with a hashed timestamp.

```
$registration->key = md5(time());
```

The idea is that no one can access this page without having the key slug/unique link.

I was wondering if this way of a 'paylink' is safe as long as I am setting the page meta 'robots' to 'none'.

Comment: Why try to reinvent the wheel when there is bundles and frameworks you can add into Laravel that has similar functionality already time tested, and proven among other top level developers?

Comment: Just keep in mind that request path will be visible in the browser history.

Comment: Googled "Laravel customer pay bundle" and dozens of sites came up with bundles... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing for example seems close to what you're asking for.

Comment: @Kray Because I like to build things like this. I was just wondering if it is safe or not.

Comment: I would recommend installing one of those bundles, and go through the code to understand the logic in how they do certain things. If you want to build your own spin off.

Comment: The only problem I find is that all the bundles are based on users and that is something that I am not using. + All the bundles are all about paying and I only need the pay-link because I am already using the Mollie system for paying.

Comment: @Kray Is it possible for other people to go to the link or is it maybe unsafe in any other way?